# How can I extract two values from a string like this using a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

How can I get the value from the following strings using one regular expression?

```
/*##debug_string:value/##*/
```

or

```
/*##debug_string:1234/##*/
```

or

```
/*##debug_string:http://stackoverflow.com//##*/
```

The result should be

```
value
1234
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Comment: You must post your tries.

Comment: What environment/language?

Comment: using python, tried varitions of ^(/\*##debug_string:)[*]/##\*/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to read behind your pattern

```
re.findall("/\*##debug_string:(.*?)/##\*/", your_string)
```

Note that your variations cannot work because you didn't escape the `*`. In regular expressions, `*` mean a repetition of the previous character/group. If you really mean the `*` character, you must use `\*`.

```
import re
print re.findall("/\*##debug_string:(.*?)/##\*/", "/*##debug_string:value/##*/")
print re.findall("/\*##debug_string:(.*?)/##\*/", "/*##debug_string:1234/##*/")
print re.findall("/\*##debug_string:(.*?)/##\*/", "/*##debug_string:http://stackoverflow.com//##*/")
```

Executes as:

```
['value']
['1234']
['http://stackoverflow.com/']
```

**EDIT:** Ok I see that you can have a URL. I've amended the pattern to take it into account.

Comment: update : unfortunately I did not take a special usage case into account when originally posting the question, and the pattern doesn't match it

Comment: Ok I see: it's the URL. Check the amended pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
[^:]+:([^/]+)
```

And use capture group #1 for your value.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/FxFnpfPHFn

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will be something like: `.*:(.*)/.+`. Group 1 will be what you are looking for. However this is a REALLY inclusive regex, you might want to post some more details so that you can create some more restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the format stays consistent:

```
re.findall('debug_string:([^\/]+)\/##', string)
```